# I'm writing an English essay and I just wanted to check if this makes sense :

Tags: grammaticality

..... I agree with the statement that Boland's reflective insights are expressed through her precise use of language. ***We see this statement to be true in*** 'Child of Our Time'.....

Comment: It makes sense, but is verbose.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not "wrong" but there are better options

I think it's grammatically correct but it is a bit unnaturally phrased. You might try one of these instead:

> This is true in *Child of Our Time.*
>
> We see this in *Child of Our Time.*
>
> We see an example of this in *Child of Our Time.* (or We see examples of this ...)

Comment: thank you very much,I was having trouble formulating a proper conclusion